# Symfony Doctrine get Country as Array

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

is it somehow possible to get an array of array with Doctrine?

In this Example I want that the country should be an array.

```
$user['country']['name'] 

or

$user['country']['cid']
```

The current Request of me :

```
    $query = $this->createQueryBuilder('u')
        ->select('u')
        ->getQuery();
    return $query->getResult(\Doctrine\ORM\Query::HYDRATE_ARRAY);
```

I only get the Id's here.

Doctrine Entities with yml:

User:

```
TestBundle\Entity\User:
    type: entity
    table: user
    repositoryClass: TestBundle\Entity\UserRepository
    id:
        uid:
            type: integer
            nullable: false
            unsigned: true
            id: true
            generator:
                strategy: IDENTITY
    fields:
        firstname:
            type: string
            nullable: true
            length: 255
            fixed: false
        lastname:
            type: string
            nullable: true
            length: 255
            fixed: false
        email:
            type: string
            nullable: true
            length: 255
            fixed: false
    oneToOne:
        country:
            targetEntity: Country
            joinColumn:
                name: country
                referencedColumnName: cid
    lifecycleCallbacks: {  }
```

Country:

```
TestBundle\Entity\Country:
    type: entity
    table: country
    repositoryClass: TestBundle\Entity\CountryRepository
    id:
        cid:
            type: integer
            nullable: false
            unsigned: false
            id: true
            generator:
                strategy: IDENTITY
    fields:
        cid:
            type: integer
            nullable: true
            unsigned: false
            options:
                default: 0
        name:
            type: string
            nullable: true
            length: 255
            fixed: false
    lifecycleCallbacks: {  }
```

It depends on speed in my example, because I have around 10 000 Object's.

Another solution would be, to write an SQL-Statement, with a lot "joins"
because this example above is only a shorten one, I have around 7 of this columns, like "group" etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of hydrating an array, you could simply use objects. Then you can access `Country` attributes via the getters you should have defined in your model class. If you really need an array, you could use php to fill them.

But if you really need speed, you should in fact consider using a raw select statement, which can be - regardless of complexity - be optimized a lot better than Doctrine could possibly do.

Comment: Did that help? Or is there still something open with your question?